# How to limit queue space in waiting area

Tags: anylogic

Hi I am a beginner at AnyLogic. I would appreciate if someone could help me. I have the task to create a call center model in which I have 3 customer service representatives, Customers calls arrive to the call center according to a Poisson process with rate λ = 15 per, The customer service times are exponentially distributed with a mean of 10 minutes. There are 24 phone lines and in case all lines are busy then the call is lost. What is the easiest way to limit queue space in the waiting area?

Comment: you need a queue with capacity 24 followed by a delay with capacity 3... that's all

Comment: here's a solution to this identical question in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72117038/if-all-of-the-service-representatives-are-busy-an-arriving-customer-is-placed-o